# Why am I automatically logged out of django admin

Tags: python, django, nginx

I deployed a Django website with Nginx on DigitalOcean and now I'm having the problem that I can login to admin but if I'm logged in for a short time I get logged out automatically

Comment: Many things can cause this. I would check if sessionid cookie set properly with correct timeout and if yes, then I would follow http request through your system and find a place where sessionid cookie gets dropped from HTTP header or not recognised as valid Django session.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.